# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException class not registered

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Receiving this error in a project where I have added a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word version 14.

I am assuming that this means that a dll is not registered. In the Properties for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word the path is shown as:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA
>   \Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll

I tried registering the dll manually but I receive this error:

> The Module "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" was loaded but the entry-point > DllRegisterServer was not found.
>
> Make sure that "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then
>   try again.

I have Microsoft Office Home and Student installed on the development machine. My best guess is that Home and Student licenses do not grant access to the registered dlls for development.

Anyone know if this is true and how I might resolve this situation?

Comment: When you say register manually...you mean regsvr32?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Which .NET version? Which VS.NET IDE?

Comment: .NET 4 Visual Studio 2010. My installation of Office is also 2010. The development machine is Win7 64bit.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with PIA? You should be using the VS.NET project templates for Word 2010 Add-in, Document, or Template (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8553caee.aspx)